# Target multiple form elements on one condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a long sign up form, and it's fields need to be validated. Most of the inputs are just text, but there's one checkbox for conditions and two radio buttons for gender.

So I'm trying to trigger validation **if** any of the inputs are empty, conditions aren't checked or gender selected, and this isn't working for me:

```
if(((Nimi&&Osoite&&Postinumero&&Postitoimipaikka&&Postinumero&&Puhelin&&Sahkoposti&&Kurssi&&Kurssilaiset&&Koiranimi&&Koiraika&&Koirarotu)=="") || ((Sukupuoli)=="Valitse")) || ((Ehdot):not(:checked))){
//Input validation

//Gender Validation

//Conditions?
}
```

There's also a syntax error I think, but how would I get it working?

**To be clear:**

I want the validation only to trigger if any of the inputs is empty, checkbox not checked or radio selected.

Comment: You are checking first to see if each is not "falsy", then you are doing a check against this aggregate boolean value against a string. You need to check each element for `==""`, there is no syntactic sugar for it.

Comment: And another Syntax error is you have an extra ) after Valitse" that closes the entire condition clause prematurely.

Comment: @Asad I've used `if((var1&&var2)=""){//dosomething}` and it triggered the validation when var1 OR/AND var2 were empty.

Comment: @Brant removing the extra ) didn't remove the error.

Comment: That's why I said "another syntax error". It wasn't your only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(Nimi&&Osoite&&Postinumero&&Postitoimipaikka&&Postinumero&&Puhelin&&Sahkoposti&&Kurssi&&Kurssilaiset&&Koiranimi&&Koiraika&&Koirarotu)
```

Results in a boolean value that is `true` if all of those variables are non-"falsy" values and `false` if any are "falsy". Then you are taking that boolean and comparing it to the empty string for equality. Aka, always `false`.

You need to explicitly compare all of them against the emtpy string. Also, you need to use the `||` (or) operator. Because you want it to run if *any* are empty. Not just if all are.

```
(Nimi==="")||(Osoite==="")||...
```

EDIT: I've changed the equality operators to `===` which means the compare is strict and therefor non-type-converting. For example, here are some differences between "falsy" values using `==` and the strict comparisons with `===`:

```
"" ==  false // true
"" === false // false
```

Comment: If I have to do it like this, why `if((var1&&var2)=""){//dosomething}` works?

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen Well, you are using an assignment there which should throw an error as you cannot assign `""` to `(var1&&var2)`. If it were `==` then yes, it might still seem to evaluate correctly but you should be using `===` which is a strict compare. I'll edit my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: Fine, I'll do it the hard way then... :)

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen I've added info about the problems with `==` in javascript and the proper solution using `===`

Answer (score 2):

Mother of god. This is why [jQuery Validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) exists. Use it, it's amazing.

Comment: It's very unclear to me how I'm supposed to use jQuery Validate plugin with ajax form submit, so I won't use it.

Comment: Curious; that's likely already been answered on SO, and if not, I'd be glad to help you. It's darn easy to do ajax submits with jQuery Validate. You just move your submit into the `submitHandler` property/method.

Answer (score 0):

The && condition should work.  If you && a bunch of strings together and one is "" then the whole evaluation becomes "", otherwise it becomes the value of the last string.

I think the issue is how you check if the checkbox is selected.  If $ is jQuery then the correct syntax would be:

```
!$j("selector").is(":checked")
```